# regex for an array of result

Tags: regex

Can anyone provide me with a regex for an array that I have translated using google translate. This array contains about 5000 entries. I want to extract the value of that array and replace it in another array 
Ex:

```
'comments_label' => 'Comments'
```

I want to select only the value of this array starting from => to the end of the quote " ' ".

i hope i am clear about the issue and thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the single quotes as well as the phrase:

```
(?<==>) *(['\w ]+)
```

If you do not want the single quotes:

```
(?<==>) *'([\w ]+)
```

To also match ' inside words, but without matching the surrounding quotes:

```
(?<==> )'\K([\w' ]+)(?=')
```

Comment: thank you ; it does the job for the most of the part , if there is a way to avoid the quotes in phrases that have "don't" for example ?

Comment: What do you mean avoid? You want to match don't but not 'don't' or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

`=>\s*'(.*)'` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aF9kV0/2)

We are looking for the presence of `=>`, then skipping any/all the whitespaces, and then capturing everything in between the single quotes.